# Sorting JSON data client side

Tags: json, jquery

I have the following script which combines 2 feeds together:

```
$(document).Ready(function() {
    url = 'feed 1';
    url_2 = 'feed 2';

    $.when(
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
            dataType: 'json'
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url_2),
            dataType: 'json'
        })
    ).done(function(a1, a2) {
        var data = a1[0].responseData.feed.entries.concat(a2[0].responseData.feed.entries);
        if (data[0]) {
            for (i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
                document.write(data[i].title);
                document.write("<br>");
                document.write(data[i].categories[0]);
                document.write("<br>");
                document.write(data[i].publishedDate);
                document.write("<br>");
                document.write(data[i].link);
                document.write("<hr>");
            }
        } 
        else {
            document.write("No records");
        }
    });
});
```

How do I go about sorting the joined feeds by `publishedDate`?

I think I'm supposed to use `jquery.sort`, but can't figure out how to use it with my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.v > b.v) {
        return 1
    }
    if (a.v < b.v) {
        return -1
    }
    return 0;
});
```

**Notes**

- change `v` to the variable name of the published data
- `data` should be an array of the feeds

Comment: This seems to be giving me strange results, i.e. 12 aug 2013, 16 sep 2013, 12 may 2013.  I was expecting, 16 sep 2013, 12 aug 2013, 12 may 2013.

Comment: @oshirowanen change the `return 1` to `return -1` and vice versa

Comment: Still seems completely random, i.e. in the same month and year, I am getting 19, 22, 15 of september 2013, then 12 may 2013?

Comment: @oshirowanen can you create a jsfiddle, and then I will give it a bash there